# OrientDB 3.x - orientdb-gremlin - Edge Index Lookup

Tags: orientdb, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I created an inout edge index. How can I now iterate over the edges if I know the in and out elementId?

With Tinkerpop 2.4 this was done via:

> Iterable edges = orientBaseGraph.getEdges("e." + edgeLabel + "_inout", new OCompositeKey(fromId, toId));

What is the Tinkerpop 3.x / orientdb-gremlin way of doing this task?

Comment: Hi Jotschi there is no such method available in TP3. I think the best way is to use traversal. Like  g.E().hasLabel("HasBar").has("in", v2.id()).has("out", v1.id()); 

It should work by passing ORecordId in has filter

Comment: If not you can raise an issue here
https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-gremlin/issues